# CSS first-of-type and last-of-type do not work

Tags: html, css

```css
.bwrapa {
  background: gold;
}

.bwrapa:first-of-type {
  background: blue;
}

.bwrapa:last-of-type {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='abc'>lorem</div>
  <div class='abc'>lorem</div>
  <div class='bwrapa'>lorem</div>
  <div class='abc'>lorem</div>
  <div class='bwrapa'>lorem</div>
  <div class='bwrapa'>lorem</div>
  <div class='abc'>lorem</div>
</div>
```

Why do all `bwrapa` classes have `background: gold`?

First and Last of them should have `background: blue` - shouldn't it?

What seems to be the problem and how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.bwrapa:first-of-type` will select the first child `<div>` of each parent element (since `.bwrapa` is a div element), not the first element with class `bwrapa`. See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) for more info.

Comment: I see... and that's so stupid system. There is no way to select first and last instance of a class?

Comment: @puerto Read the linked duplicate

Comment: @puerto unfortunately it is not possible. You will need to use javascript. Hope it will be implemented in the next version of CSS.